# RESTful web service API documentation with Sphinx

Tags: rest, documentation, python-sphinx

What's the best way to markup methods/URLs for a RESTful webservice using ReST/Sphinx? Is there a default domain that's suitable for marking up URLs with their possible parameters, HTTP methods, headers and body content?

Something along the lines of:

```
.. rest:method:: GET /api/foo

   :param bar: A valid bar
   :extension: json or xml

   Retrieve foos for the given parameters. E.g.::

      GET /api/foo.json?bar=baz
```

Does something like this already exist or is one of the default extensions usable, or will I have to write one myself?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? facing the the same "problem" :)

Comment: @Henrik See [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545828/web-service-api-documentation-with-sphinx/4732927#4732927).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [Sphinx Contrib](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx-contrib) project also seems to have an *HTTP Domain* package for documenting RESTful HTTP APIs. You can find its documentation on the [Python packages](http://packages.python.org/sphinxcontrib-httpdomain) site. I can't speak to its fitness: I'm only just starting to look into Sphinx, and I have a need to document RESTful APIs as well, and noticed this contributed package.

Comment: +1.  I tried this extension today, and found it to be a really good start.  It also comes with a module that can scan a Flask application's routing table for documentation, much like autodoc.  (I haven't tried that part yet.)

Comment: Marking this one as accepted, as it's the better maintained package I think. My version is essentially abandoned for now (though it does work as is).

Comment: I can now comment that we've been using Sphinx (with the _HTTP Domain_ package) in production for a year, and it's doing the job just fine. I have made a few local changes to tailor it for our particular needs, but in general, I am quite pleased with the results.

Comment: Note: sphinxcontrib.autohttp.tornado only works for Python 2.x since it imports StringIO.

Comment: @proteneer, As far as I know, this is not the extension package I am referring to: I am referring to `sphinxcontrib-httpdomain`.

Comment: httpdomain has an extension for tornado/flask/bottle/etc.

Comment: Ah! I see. This was not clear to me, and I don't use this functionality, so was not aware of it's problems.

Answer (score 18):

Since there doesn't appear to be any existing solution, I have implemented a very simple HTTP domain that I can use to mark up API methods:

```
import re

from docutils import nodes

from sphinx import addnodes
from sphinx.locale import l_, _
from sphinx.domains import Domain, ObjType
from sphinx.directives import ObjectDescription


http_method_sig_re = re.compile(r'^(GET|POST|PUT|DELETE)?\s?(\S+)(.*)$')

class HTTPMethod(ObjectDescription):

    def handle_signature(self, sig, signode):
        m = http_method_sig_re.match(sig)
        if m is None:
            raise ValueError

        verb, url, query = m.groups()
        if verb is None:
            verb = 'GET'

        signode += addnodes.desc_addname(verb, verb)
        signode += addnodes.desc_name(url, url)

        if query:
            params = query.strip().split()
            for param in params:
                signode += addnodes.desc_optional(param, param)

        return url


class HTTPDomain(Domain):
    """HTTP language domain."""
    name = 'http'
    label = 'HTTP'
    object_types = {
        'method':    ObjType(l_('method'),    'method')
    }
    directives = {
        'method':       HTTPMethod
    }

def setup(app):
    app.add_domain(HTTPDomain)
```

It allows me to mark up methods like this and they'll be styled somewhat visually nicely:

```
.. http:method:: GET /api/foo/bar/:id/:slug

   :param id: An id
   :param slug: A slug

   Retrieve list of foobars matching given id.
```

This was my first foray into both Sphinx and Python, so this should be considered very rudimentary code. If anybody is interested in fleshing this out, please [fork this project on Github](https://github.com/deceze/Sphinx-HTTP-domain)!

Comment: great! thanks! you should add the term Restful to the title to get a higher google pagerank on this topic :) I could do it, but I don't like messing with good questions.

Comment: @Henrik Good point. :) I'm thinking about throwing this up on Github to allow for some collaborative development. What do you think?

Comment: Wouldn't harm anyone if its over on the Githubs ;)

Comment: I installed this from the python package index today, and it didn't work at all.  This exception was raised:  TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'can_collapse'